# IOS custom UINavigationItem leftBarButtonItem hotspots range is too big

Tags: ios, button, user-interface, action, uibarbuttonitem

`iOS` custom `UINavigationItem leftBarButtonItem` hotspots range is too big

```
UIButton *modalViewButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage* imagex = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_backX1.png"];
[modalViewButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(backAction:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[modalViewButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_backX1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//image size is 35X34
[modalViewButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imagex.size.width, imagex.size.height)];
UIBarButtonItem *modalBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:modalViewButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = modalBarButtonItem;
[modalBarButtonItem release];
```

when i click the `UIView` on left top Under `UINavigationBar` the `leftBarButtonItem`
,that will action.
and if i click middle of `UINavigationBar`,the `leftBarButtonItem` action too.
How to modify the hotspots range to make it smaller?